# Fetching XML attributes in Python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, python-3.x

For example i have the following XML file:
In each phrase, I always have 2 `<en>` tags and `x` attribute is either PERS, LOC or ORG.
What I want to do is get all `<en>` pairs in which they are ORG & PERS only

XML Sample:

```
<PHRASE>
<N y='0'> back</N>
<en x='PERS'>John</en>
<PREP>to</PREP>
<en x='LOC'>New York</en>
</PHRASE>
```

I am using element tree, I tried that, but it retrieves any PERS or ORG no matter what is the second "en" tag. And I only want PERS and ORG pairs (i.e.: when they appear in the same phrase)

```
for en in root.findall('./PHRASE/en'):
    NE = en.get('x')
    if(NE) == "ORG":
     print("ORG is: ",en.text)
    NE2=en.get('x')
    if(NE2) == "PERS":
        print("PER is:", en.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find special phrases, you have to iterate over phrases and test them to fulfill the condition:

```
for phrase in root.findall('./PHRASE'):
    ens = {en.get('x'): en.text for en in phrase.findall('en')}
    if 'ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens:
        print("ORG is: {}, PERS is: {}".format(ens["ORG"], ens["PERS"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You *don't have to iterate over all phrases*. Use the power of [`XPath`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to filter out `PHRASE` elements where the first `en`'s x attribute is `PERS` and the second `en`'s x attribute is `LOC`:

```
root.xpath(".//PHRASE[en[1]/@x = 'PERS' and en[2]/@x = 'LOC']")
```

Assuming you are using [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/).